# Android remote service query

Tags: android, aidl

If i want to call a function of a remote service from within the UI thread.. how do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AsyncTask to call a remote service. This performs background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads .

[check this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)